#  DataTable convert field value to T

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

I have the following function:

```
public T GetScalar<T>(string sql, T defaultValue, SQLParam[] sqlParams = null)
{
    DataTable dt = GetDataTable(sql, sqlParams);
    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0) return defaultValue;
    else
    {
        try
        {
            object tmp = dt.Rows[0][0];
            return (T)tmp;
        }
        catch { return defaultValue; }
    }
}
```

I am getting an `InvalidCastException`.

During debugging, I can see the value of `tmp` is 3, and `T` is of type `int`.

What is the problem here?

**EDIT**

A bit of background: This used to work in MySQL. I have now moved to SQLServer (with little effort thankfully) but this code now fails.

Comment: Why the declaration of object in the first place? Why not just `T tmp`?

Comment: If you only want a scalar, why are you loading into a `DataTable` in the first place? (this is purely out of curiosity)

Comment: @Joel - I only put the tmp in there for debugging, initially it was `return (T)dt.Rows[0][0]`

Comment: Maybe you also want to use the [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301394) method to access the datarow.

Comment: It's strange - this used to work in MySQL (with the exact same code) - but now i need to move to SQLServer for other reasons. This code now breaks.

Comment: If I put a watch on `tmp`, the `Type` displays `object {int}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the value is *actually* a `long`, or something like that - and when you unbox, you have to unbox to the *exact* type (there are a few oddities around signedness and enums, but not `long` vs `int`).

You should be able to see this if you put a watch on `tmp.GetType()` - or just work out what type it should be from the SQL.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Asleep at the wheel :(

Comment: The watch just showed it was of Type `object {int}`. The database type is also int. Confused why it doesn't work, but Michal's solution works for now

Comment: @Simon: Did you actually call `GetType()` though? It would be very strange if you really did have an int and couldn't convert to it...

Comment: This is what I get: `Type t2 = tmp.GetType()` =  `t2 {Name = "Int32", FullName = "System.Int32"}`

Comment: @Simon: And `typeof(T)`? Can you produce a short but complete program demonstrating this? I find it hard to believe you've managed to break unboxing...

Comment: There must be something going on somewhere else in my code, I am currently offshore so I will try when I get a chance. It is puzzling, yes.

Comment: You were correct, (as always) - the return type was actually a decimal - the result of a `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` call.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your line:

```
return (T)tmp;
```

to

```
return (T) Convert.ChangeType(tmp, typeof(T));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing you code in the `try` block to this:

```
        T tmp = dt.Rows[0].Field<T>(0);
        return tmp;
```

See if that works - or at the very least gives you a better error. :-)